# Is there anyway to create a background process service that will run whether or not the app created it is still running?

Tags: android, service, background-process

So, I want my app to create a Service that will initially run in the background and do some stuff. This background process will never stop. It will constantly keep running. The ONLY way the background process can be created or destroyed would be through the app. I understand that there are endless possibilities to kill a process. I guess I want my app to be able to tell me whether or not the process is running and retrieve real time information from that process. Along with that, be able to start and/or destroy the background process.

So, let's say that you were to open the app and start/create the service. Even when you close/terminal/call onDestroy for the app, I still want the background process to be running. The only way to destroy this service would be to re-open/re-create the app, and destroy it.

Does Android allow something like this? Is there a way to get around this?

I was going to create a `IntentService` and make it run an infinite loop. Though, my only problem is how to obtain information from the `IntentService`. From what I've learned, an `IntentService` is created and kills itself when it's done.

I'm still new to Android, so don't hesitate to be specific and/or remedial.

Comment: Did you read this guide? http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to make 2 apps for that, in fact, if your requirement is to only be able to stop/create the service from the main app it will only overcomplicate things (such as that you dont need aidl at all since its all in the same app) , that goes for the above answer (cant reply yet!).

Just create the app and the service class even on the same package as the other activities. Then on the manifest xml register the service like this at the application node:

```
<service
        android:name="com.example.yourpackage.Service"
        android:process=":remote"> 
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="com.example.yourpackage.Service" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

What you are doing with the android:process=":remote" tag is explicitly setting the service to run in a different process (by the name of 'remote') than the rest of the app while still being part of it.

Then, to start and stop it simply use these from your activity:

```
startService(new Intent(this, Service.class));
```

·
·
·

```
stopService(new Intent(this, Service.class));
```

Make sure you read the documentation about services (and broadcastreceivers) anyway, but that will give you a general idea as to where to aim and what NOT to do to overcomplicate.

I've been working with services lately so im fresh on the matter, if you have any questions let me know here!

**<<<<<<<<<<<<   EDIT : >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>**

Ah I think I get you now.. if you dont want the service to keep running after the "app" is finished just forget about the :remote part. That way they will both share same app lifecycle (but not context lifecycle as they have different ones), sorry if that part confused you and thanks for the vote!.

Comment: So, my App (Activity) creates a background process (Service). Then, my App is destroyed (onDestroy) and background process is still running?

Comment: I recommend you this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html its pretty good and up to date

Comment: You can even set a broadcastreceiver to handle BOOT_COMPLETED and start the service to make sure its running after device reboot too. All that without the app running. Just remember that even if the service and the other activities run in different processes, that service is still bound to that app through the manifest. 
As you can guess services are pretty powerful resource but you need to handle them right and only extend their functionality to your bare requeriments, because else it can drain battery and/or resources pretty fast.

Comment: Another thing is that a service can be shut down by the android system any time it is "needed" (such as memory leaks which ive tested aswell as system battery-life settings which may also affect it).

Comment: So, to continue from my first comment question, now my App was destroyed and my service is still running. When I reopen/recreate the App, use the line of code `stopService(new Intent(this, Service.class));`, it will kill that same instance of the service I created the first time I opened the App?

Comment: Yes since service is a separate process if you set android:process=":remote". You can start/stop it within the app by the class pointer (not instanced). However if you dont want the service to run in a separate process check edit on my main post.

Comment: If my answer helped you, can you please set the correct answer tag for me? need the rep badly! thanks =P

Comment: @SuppressWarnings You're plain wrong. `:remote` creates a private process, which will be destroyed together with the main process of the app. To let the service be independent of the app it should at least live in its own (global) process.

Answer (score 4):

Answer is quite simple.

- Create a `Service` (not `IntentService`, just a simple `Service`) and start it from your activity. IntentService will not work in your case as it will call `stopSelf()` on itself as soon as you return from `onHandleIntent()`
- Your service will continue to run till somebody explicitly calls stop method on it or service itself calls `stopSelf()` method. But in low memory conditions, platform can kill your background services. When device has enough memory platform will restart your service provided you make your service STICKY by returning `START_STICKY` in onStartCommand().
- call `stopService()` from your activity when required. It doesn't matter even if your activity got stopped/killed and restarted.
- You dont really require to launch your service in another process. Because platform will make sure to start and keep your application process alive as long as any of its entities  (Activities, Services, Receivers) are alive. Dont worry, your application will not appear in running apps list if your process is running but none of its activities are alive.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Just make 2 apps. one a service and one an app. (since the service & the app run on the 'UI' thread).. That way you have two separate processes. Use aidl to communicate between the two.. Would not use intent service, those are supposed to be short lived.

Comment: I'm guessing the "service" app won't act like a normal app? Will you be able to see it in the app drawer?

Comment: the problem with this though is that the OS can always kill the service if the OS needs resources so it is not possible for only your app to kill a service. creating a seperate "app" that is just a service seems pretty silly and unneeded because you can start and stop it in just a normal app

Comment: @tyczj I understand that there are endless possibilities to kill a process. I guess I want my app to be able to tell me whether or not the process is running and retrieve real time information from that process. Along with that, be able to start and/or destroy the background process.

Comment: @RobAveryIV you can do this just fine by starting the service normally in your app and binding to that service

Answer (score 0):

The solution the user SupressWarnings gave you is correct, except that you will be forcing the Service to run in a separate process, and I don't think you will be interested in that. It will only help you in keeping your service running even after the main process dies (probably because of an unhandled Exception), but the fact is that the main process should never die if you have a service running. And the problem with having your service in a separate VM process is that you will lose the ability to use the same memory space, so singletons, statics variables, etc., won't work as expected. And additionally every call from the main process to the service process will be serialized through the binder mechanism which incurs in speed penalties and limits the serialized data to not go beyond 1MB (which could happen if you pass a big byte array for example).
So my opinion is that you should use the SupressWarnings solution without the android:process attribute.

Comment: Probably what he didn't tell you is that you should extend from Service class instead of IntentService. And then you should override the onstartcommand method and implement your logic there. Read the official Android documentation and it will help you understand better the Service concept.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and I fixed it by calling `startForeground()` within my `onStartCommand()` of a regular `Service`, not `IntentService`. I recommend you make the switch to a regular `Service` as mentioned above.

Here is my code. Call this method in your `onStartCommand()`:

```
final int id = 1234;
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

//Build the notification
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getBaseContext());
builder.setContentIntent(pendIntent);
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
builder.setTicker("message");
builder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
builder.setAutoCancel(false);
builder.setContentTitle("Test Service");
builder.setContentText("message");

Notification notification = builder.build();

//start foreground service
startForeground(id, notification);
```